# Letter or icon for app icon

Tags: icon

Do you guys think a letter (like Vine, tumblr, Facebook, Vimeo) is a better representation of a brand/app than an icon (like SnapChat, Evernote, Twitter, Dropbox)?

Comment: I think it depends.

Comment: Hey @A user this is a really broad question and would definitely depend on the context of the app. There is no right or wrong answer :)

Comment: Actually, brands you mentioned don't have separate symbol and typographical. Would be strange if Facebook or Vimeo would use some symbol for app icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think depends on strength of a brand.

Icons - images are much more recognizable for eye because they are complex. But thats just visuality.

I don't think just letters are good representation a especially if its a small brand. There is only finite number of letters and their shapes. But for big brands i think it works because... well they are everywhere so you have no problem to remember and recognise them. The simplicity makes them more grand somehow.

Also note, the brands that use just letters almost aways connect strong color with very specific typeface (Klavika that Facebook uses for example).

I don't think its so simple though. Branding can be pretty complicated.

Btw there is great free resource (course) on branding from Wolff Olins - [Secred Power of Brands](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/secret-power-of-brands-3)

Answer (score -1):

Icon is better, that letter like "F" (in facebook) is a icon, mind sees as a image

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! Though we get your general point, I would suggest you edit your question to expand and explain your view, with reason and preferably examples. This site is based on the expectation that people give good, well reasoned answers.